# Erro 400 Bad Resquest no React Native com Axios

Tags: react-native, axios

Fiz este código me baseando em um projeto de React. Utilizando o axios e o react native, estou tentando retornar os dados da array, mas só está retornando no log um erro 400 no request da api.

Aqui está o código:

main.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Weather from '../services/weather';
import axios from 'axios';
import{ View, Text, TextInput, Button } from 'react-native';

export default class Main extends Component {

    static navigationOptions = {
        title: "Open Weather"
    }

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          weather: [],
          temp: [],
          clouds: []
        }
    }

    getWeather = query => {
        axios.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=${query}&units=metric&appid=6724e5bbc20ecbdb04109535892e5e49`)
          .then(response => {
            this.setState({
              weather: response.data.list[0],
              temp: response.data.list[0].main.temp,
              clouds: response.data.list[0].weather[0].description
            });
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log('Error', error);
          });
      };

    queryWeather = (event, cityName) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            cityName = event.target.value;
            this.getWeather(cityName);            
    }


    render(){
        return(
            <View>
                <Text>Cidade: </Text>
                <TextInput queryWeather={this.queryWeather} 
                    style={{ height: 40, borderColor: '#dfdfdf', borderWidth: 1 }} 
                    placeholder={'Digite o nome da cidade...'}                    
                />
                <Button title="Buscar" onPress={this.queryWeather}/>
                <Weather
                    city={this.state.weather.name}
                    temp={this.state.temp}
                    clouds={this.state.clouds} 
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

weather.js

```
import React from 'react';

import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

const Weather = props =>

    <View>
        <Text>Cidade: {props.city}</Text>
        <Text>Temperatura: {props.temp}</Text>
        <Text>Céu: {props.clouds}</Text>
    </View>

export default Weather;
```

Answer (score 1):

Para começar, diria que seu código está bagunçado, de certa forma suas funções estão equivocadas já que ao clicar no botão é chamada uma função que pegará o valor do input e depois chamará a função para realizar a requisição, sendo desnecessário realizar todo esse processo. No fim das contas a variavel `query` que chega na função que fará a requisição tem o valor de `undefined` causando o erro 400 que é mostrado. [Demo aqui](https://snack.expo.io/@sant0will/shallow-truffles)

Ao invés de ter a função "queryWeather" que pega o valor do input, penso que seja a melhor forma, pode utilizar um `state` e atribuir o a entrada do teclado a esse estado. O seu `TextInput` passa a ser da seguinte forma:

```
<TextInput 
    style={{ height: 40, borderColor: '#dfdfdf', borderWidth: 1 }} 
    placeholder={'Digite o nome da cidade...'}  
    onChangeText={(search) => { this.setState({ search }) }} 
    // O estado search alterado acima deve ser préviamente criado
/>
```

Por fim, chamamos diretamente a função "getWeather" e não a "queryWeather", e como tens no estado `search` o valor que o usuário digitou, basta adicionar o `this.state.search` na url para realizar a requisição, ficando da seguinte forma:

```
getWeather = () => {
    axios.get("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q="+this.state.search+"&units=metric&appid=6724e5bbc20ecbdb04109535892e5e49")
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        this.setState({
          weather: response.data.list[0],
          temp: response.data.list[0].main.temp,
          clouds: response.data.list[0].weather[0].description
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('Error', error);
      });
  };
```

Tens [aqui](https://snack.expo.io/@sant0will/ba0ed2) todo o código funcionando. Algumas dicas:

- Busque sempre quais os metodos de um componente (TextInput -> OnChangeText), na maioria dos casos haverá um apropriado para o seu caso (Use a documentação).
- Utilize os logs (console.log(var)),  assim será mais fácil perceber oque tem de errado em seu código.
- Mantenha o código simples e seja sempre objetivo.